# Change the FontStyle in code behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

How can I change the `FontStyle` in the code-behind in WPF. I tried this:

```
listBoxItem.FontStyle = new FontStyle("Italic");
```

and I got error, any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It was `FontStyles.Italic`... Use the `FontStyles` enum to set the value for `FontStyle`

```
listBoxItem.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `FontStyles.Italic`

```
listBoxItem.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
```

Comment: It must be FontStyle`s`.Italic;.

Comment: i try like it but I got erorr ,cannot resolve symbol italic ,any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation `FontStyle` is structure [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.fontstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Defines a structure that represents the style of a font face as normal, italic, or oblique.

It can be viewed in `ILSpy`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(FontStyleConverter)), Localizability(LocalizationCategory.None)]
public struct FontStyle : IFormattable
{
    private int _style;

    internal FontStyle(int style)
    {
        this._style = style;
    }
```

Here we see that the field `_style` of type *`Int`*. To set the value of `Int` type , it is taken from the static class `FontStyles`:

```
public static class FontStyles
{
     public static FontStyle Normal
     {
        get
        {
            return new FontStyle(0);
        }
    }

    public static FontStyle Oblique
    {
        get
        {
            return new FontStyle(1);
        }
    }

    public static FontStyle Italic
    {
        get
        {
            return new FontStyle(2);
        }
    }

    internal static bool FontStyleStringToKnownStyle(string s, IFormatProvider provider, ref FontStyle fontStyle)
    {
        if (s.Equals("Normal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            return true;
        }

        if (s.Equals("Italic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            return true;
        }

        if (s.Equals("Oblique", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            fontStyle = FontStyles.Oblique;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So it turns out, to setting `FontStyle` need to refer to a static class `FontStyles`:

```
SomeControl.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
```

There can be a bit confusing, in fact there are two `FontStyle` (without s) enumerations:

**`namespace MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface`**

```
internal enum FontStyle
{
    Italic = 2,
    Oblique = 1,
    Normal = 0
}
```

This enumeration are *Internal* and I think used inside the system in conjunction with an public structure `FontStyles`.

**`namespace System.Drawing`**

```
[Flags]
public enum FontStyle
{
    Regular = 0,
    Bold = 1,
    Italic = 2,
    Underline = 4,
    Strikeout = 8
 }
```

This flags enumeration is *Public* and used in `System.Drawing` like this:

```
SomeControl.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,
                        12.0F, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
```